# C#. Как установить таймаут бездействия в элементе WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser

Если пользователь открыл в программе элемент WebBrowser и долго его не использует, то как сделать таймаут, допустим на 10 минут бездействия? И по истечению времени, возврат в главное окно.

Comment: у вас проект `winforms` или `wpf`?

Comment: Foggy Finder. Извиняюсь,что не указал. Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Набросок кода такой, далее сами уже подрихтуйте.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //таймер
    private Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //настройка таймера
        SetupTimer();

        //настройка WebBrowser и загрузка сайта
        LoadSO();
    }

    private void SetupTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();

        //1000 == 1 sec.
        //ставим интервал на 10 сек.
        _timer.Interval = 10000;

        //подписка на событие истечения интервала
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;

    }

    //событие истечения интервала
    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //таймер сработал, закрываем форму
        this.Close();
    }

    private void LoadSO()
    {
        string so = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions";

        //подписка на событие "Документ загружен"
        this._webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += _webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        //подписка на событие "Загрузка по новому адресу"
        this._webBrowser.Navigating += _webBrowser_Navigating;

        //гасим сообщения об ошибках в скриптах на сайте
        this._webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        //загружаем сайт
        this._webBrowser.Url = new Uri(so);
    }

    //событие "Загрузка по новому адресу"
    private void _webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        //прерываем таймер
        _timer.Stop();
    }

    //событие "Документ загружен"
    private void _webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //запускаем таймер
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bulson. Спасибо большое! А с Awesomium не работали? Там не знаете на какое событие вешать timer.stop?

Comment: @technor Нет, извините, не работал.